# o virtual method getParcelableArrayList(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)

Tags: android

this is my code I am sending data from fragment to activity using putParcelableArrayList and getParcelableArrayList this works android os 13 properly

```
 override fun onClickProfilePost(position: Int) {
        val intent = Intent(requireContext(), SelfPostDetailPageActivity::class.java)
        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putParcelableArrayList(
            "PostData",
            listOfPost
        )
        intent.putExtras(bundle)
        intent.putExtra("position", position)
        context?.startActivity(intent)
    }



val bundle = intent.extras
        listOfPost = bundle?.getParcelableArrayList(
            "PostData",
            PostsList::class.java
        ) as ArrayList<PostsList>
```

but when I try to run this code in os 11 then I am getting below error

```
E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.unik.shootup, PID: 9438
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getParcelableArrayList(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/util/ArrayList; in class Landroid/os/Bundle; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.os.Bundle' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar!classes2.dex)
    at com.unik.shootup.selfpostdetail.view.SelfPostDetailPageActivity.onCreate(SelfPostDetailPageActivity.kt:38)
```

can any one please help me what I am doing wrong I can fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below extension method:

```
inline fun <reified T : Parcelable> Bundle.parcelableArrayList(key: String): ArrayList<T>? = when {
  SDK_INT >= 33 -> getParcelableArrayList(key, T::class.java)
  else -> @Suppress("DEPRECATION") getParcelableArrayList(key)
}

inline fun <reified T : Parcelable> Intent.parcelableArrayList(key: String): ArrayList<T>? = when {
  SDK_INT >= 33 -> getParcelableArrayListExtra(key, T::class.java)
  else -> @Suppress("DEPRECATION") getParcelableArrayListExtra(key)
}
```

Check [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle#getParcelableArrayList(java.lang.String)) for API Level 33

Comment: Thanks @Mohammad Misbah can you tell me which line of code we have to user seems both are same

Comment: You may use the first one as you used getParcelableArrayList, not getParcelableArrayListExtra

Comment: can you please tell me how to call this function

Comment: Simply call this method 'parcelableArrayList' with bundle instance.  Please refer this  for more clarity: https://rommansabbir.com/kotlin-inline-extension-function